# Prevent identical pairs when shuffling and slicing Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, shuffle

I'd like to prevent producing pairs with the same items when producing a random set of pairs in a Ruby array.

For example:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,4].shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
```

might produce:

```
[[1, 1], [3, 4], [2, 2]]
```

I'd like to be able to ensure that it produces a result such as:

```
[[4, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2]]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: to clarify, you are trying to prevent duplicates in any order, as in the [1,2] and [2,1]?

Comment: Sorry, I had copied the wrong array result. Example updated. Duplicates in a different order are not an issue, just not same item twice.

Comment: You have completely changed the question, and you are still unclear about what you want. Is `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4]]` acceptable?

Comment: Yes that is acceptable. My apologies.

Comment: See my answer below, which does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [1,1,2,2,3,4]
loop do
  sliced = arr.shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
  break sliced if sliced.none? { |a| a.reduce(:==) }
end
```

Comment: Wondering about the `map(&:sort)`? Is it necessary?

Comment: @seph nope :) now I’m wondering how it ever appeared there. Thanks, updated.

Comment: This is why I love Ruby. Very nice.

Comment: If `arr = [1,1,2,1]`, no matter how it's shuffled at least one slice will be `[1, 1]`, so it will never terminate. Also, if `arr` is large but `arr.uniq` is small, it may take a long time to get a solution.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways to produce the desired result (not including the approach of sampling repeatedly until a valid sample is found). The following array will be used for illustration.

```
arr = [1,4,1,2,3,2,1]
```

**Use [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sample)**

If pairs sampled were permitted to have the same number twice, the sample space would be

```
arr.combination(2).to_a
  #=> [[1, 4], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1], [4, 1], [4, 2],
  #    [4, 3], [4, 2], [4, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 3],
  #    [2, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 1], [2, 1]]
```

The pairs containing the same value twice--here `[1, 1]` and `[2, 2]`--are not wanted so they are simple removed from the above array.

```
sample_space = arr.combination(2).reject { |x,y| x==y }
  #=> [[1, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3],
  #    [4, 2], [4, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1],
  #    [3, 2], [3, 1], [2, 1]]
```

We evidently are to sample `arr.size/2` elements from `sample_space`. Depending on whether this is to be done [with or without replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) we would write

```
sample_space.sample(arr.size/2)
  #=> [[4, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

for sampling without replacement and

```
Array.new(arr.size/2) { sample_space.sample }
  #=> [[1, 3], [4, 1], [2, 1]]
```

for sampling with replacement.

**Sample elements of each pair sequentially, Method 1**

This method, like the next, can only be used to sample with replacement.

Let's first consider sampling a single pair. We could do that by selecting the first element of the pair randomly from `arr`, remove all instances of that element in `arr` and then sample the second element from what's left of `arr`.

```
def sample_one_pair(arr)
  first = arr.sample
  [first, second = (arr-[first]).sample]
end
```

To draw a sample of `arr.size/2` pairs we there execute the following.

```
Array.new(arr.size/2) { sample_one_pair(arr) }
   #=> [[1, 2], [4, 3], [1, 2]]
```

**Sample elements of each pair sequentially, Method 2**

This method is a very fast way of sampling large numbers of pairs with replacement. Like the previous method, it cannot be used to sample without replacement.

First, compute the *cdf* (cumulative distribution function) for drawing an element of `arr` at random.

```
counts = arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values { |v| v.size }
  #=> {1=>3, 4=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}

def cdf(sz, counts)
  frac = 1.0/sz
  counts.each_with_object([]) { |(k,v),a|
    a << [k, frac * v + (a.empty? ? 0 : a.last.last)] }
end

cdf_first = cdf(arr.size, counts)
  #=> [[1, 0.429], [4, 0.571], [2, 0.857], [3, 1.0]]
```

This means that there is a probability of 0.429 (rounded) of randomly drawing a `1`, 0.571 of drawing a `1` or a `4`, 0.857 of drawing a `1`, `4` or `2` and 1.0 of drawing one of the four numbers. We therefore can randomly sample a number from `arr` by obtaining a (pseudo-) random number between zero and one (`p = rand`) and then determine the first element of `counts_cdf`, `[n, q]` for which `p <= q`:

```
def draw_random(cdf)
  p = rand
  cdf.find { |n,q| p <= q }.first
end

draw_random(counts_cdf) #=> 1
draw_random(counts_cdf) #=> 4
draw_random(counts_cdf) #=> 1
draw_random(counts_cdf) #=> 1
draw_random(counts_cdf) #=> 2
draw_random(counts_cdf) #=> 3
```

In simulation models, incidentally, this is the standard way of generating pseudo-random variates from discrete probability distributions.

Before drawing the second random number of the pair we need to modify `cdf_first` to reflect that fact that the first number cannot be drawn again. Assuming there will be many pairs to generate randomly, it is most efficient to construct a hash `cdf_second` whose keys are the first values drawn randomly for the pair and whose values are the corresponding cdf's.

```
cdf_second = counts.keys.each_with_object({}) { |n, h|
  h[n] = cdf(arr.size - counts[n], counts.reject { |k,_| k==n }) }
  #=> {1=>[[4, 0.25], [2, 0.75], [3, 1.0]],
  #    4=>[[1, 0.5], [2, 0.833], [3, 1.0]],
  #    2=>[[1, 0.6], [4, 0.8], [3, 1.0]],
  #    3=>[[1, 0.5], [4, 0.667], [2, 1.0]]}
```

If, for example, a `2` is drawn for the first element of the pair, the probability is `0.6` of drawing a `1` for the second element, `0.8` of drawing a `1` or `4` and `1.0` of drawing a `1`, `4`, or `3`.

We can then sample one pair as follows.

```
def sample_one_pair(cdf_first, cdf_second)
  first = draw_random(cdf_first)
  [first, draw_random(cdf_second[first])]
end
```

As before, to sample `arr.size/2` values with replacement, we execute

```
Array.new(arr.size/2) { sample_one_pair }
  #=> [[2, 1], [3, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: RuboCop and others recommend Array.new(n) over n.times.map. And Array#- doesn't mutate the receiver, so it shouldn't be necessary to copy the array in #2.

Comment: And if you're sneaky, you can compress your function body to one line: `[(first = arr.sample), (arr-[first]).sample]`. :-)

Comment: @mwp, thanks. I implement both your suggestions (but not the third (cringe)). I've often wondered if "mwp" is short for [mugwump](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mugwump&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA752CA752&oq=mugwump&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6246j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). If they are instead initials, that might be a good nickname.

Comment: It is not, but that made me laugh!

Answer (score 1):

With replacement, you may get results like:

```
unique_pairs([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]) # => [[4, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Note that `1` gets chosen three times, even though it's only in the original array twice. This is because the `1` is "replaced" each time it's chosen. In other words, it's put back into the collection to potentially be chosen again.

Here's a version of Cary's excellent sample_one_pair solution **without** replacement:

```
def unique_pairs(arr)
  dup = arr.dup

  Array.new(dup.size / 2) do
    dup.shuffle!

    first = dup.pop
    second_index = dup.rindex { |e| e != first }
    raise StopIteration unless second_index
    second = dup.delete_at(second_index)

    [first, second]
  end
rescue StopIteration
  retry
end

unique_pairs([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]) # => [[4, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

This works by creating a copy of the original array and deleting elements out of it as they're chosen (so they can't be chosen again). The rescue/retry is in there in case it becomes impossible to produce the correct number of pairs. For example, if `[1, 3]` is chosen first, and `[1, 4]` is chosen second, it becomes impossible to make three unique pairs because `[2, 2]` is all that's left; the sample space is exhausted.

<strike>This should be slower than Cary's solution (with replacement) but faster (on average) than the posted solutions (without replacement) that require looping and retrying.</strike> Welp, chalk up another point for "always benchmark!" I was wrong about <strike>**all**</strike> most of my assumptions. Here are the results on my machine with an array of 16 numbers (`[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10]`):

```
cary_with_replacement
                         93.737k (± 2.9%) i/s -    470.690k in   5.025734s
mwp_without_replacement
                        187.739k (± 3.3%) i/s -    943.415k in   5.030774s
mudasobwa_without_replacement
                        129.490k (± 9.4%) i/s -    653.150k in   5.096761s
```

EDIT: I've updated the above solution to address Stefan's numerous concerns. In hindsight, the errors are obvious and embarrassing! On the plus side, the revised solution is now faster than mudasobwa's solution, and I've confirmed that the two solutions have the same biases.

Comment: Looks good, mudwump. I added a third method to my answer for situations were large numbers of pairs are to be selected randomly, but it's not easily comparable to the other methods suggested.

Comment: Can you share your benchmark code? I just tried like `Benchmark.measure { n.times { mwp(arr) } }` with `n = 1000000` and `arr = [1,1,2,2,3,4]` and yours was factor 1.3 *faster* than mudasobwa's. (But I'm a Ruby newb so maybe that's not a proper benchmark?)

Comment: I think you have bugs. Somtimes your code returns me an *empty* array. Always when you `retry`. I added `puts 'retry'` before the `retry` and `p arr` at the start of the method, and I'm shown that whenever you `retry`, the array is `[2]`. I think you shouldn't overwrite `arr = arr.dup` but need something like `dup = arr.dup` and then work with `dup`. Also, the retry input really *always* was `[2]`. Never `[1]`. Which is suspicious. I think it has to do with `shuffle` creating a new array, so you find an index in a shuffled copy and use that index on the unshuffled array, which makes no sense.

Comment: That latter bug also creates the possibility of pairing identical values, for example your method just gave me `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 3]]`.

Comment: And I think the whole approach is wrongly biased, even after fixing those bugs. Have a look at [this experiment](https://ideone.com/vT0FE6) and you'll for example see that results starting with `[[1, 3], [2` have a way above average probability and results starting with `[[3, 1], [1` have a way *below* average probability. The solution by mudasobwa doesn't have such a bias, and I think that's better.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thank you for all your analysis on this. I'm embarrassed by the bugs you found! I believe the revised solution should pass muster, and I've updated the benchmarks and provided the number array used for the benchmark. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, looks ok now, except for the bias (if it's unwanted). --- Which two solutions do you mean have the same biases? It sounds like you mean yours and mudasobwa's, but as I said earlier that's not the case. --- I think yours would speed up a bit by using `pop` instead of `shift`. And mudasobwa's would speed up with `{ |x, y| x == y }`. --- Not easy to guess which solution should be faster, btw. Yours does have the advantage of noticing doubles earlier, but also the disadvantage of shuffling more often. For example for `(1..16).to_a` you shuffle eight times (while mudasobwa's only does once).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ah, yes, using pop and rindex yields a 4–6% speed boost. You're a gold mine of optimization hacks! RE: bias, I compared the frequency output of this solution with mudasobwa's and they look the same. What am I not understanding?

Comment: How did you measure/compare the frequencies? And darn, I did look for `find_rindex` (which doesn't exist) and missed `rindex`. Silly Ruby confusing me with its aliases...

Comment: @StefanPochmann I just ran your ideone test with my method body and then again with mudasobwa's method body. Also, what do you think about shuffling the array just once at the top of the function? Maybe it doesn't need to be shuffled on each iteration of the loop. Been pondering this all evening.

Comment: Nope, I take it back. My method still has bias, so I'm looking into it some more.

Comment: What I think about shuffling the array just once at the top of the function? I guessed it would cause another bias, because the deliberate search and removal of a *different* second value messes up the randomness. And I just tried it and it really does look even worse. Compare the outputs: https://ideone.com/LXiMcu vs https://ideone.com/07ubVk . Although... that looks like just two different probabilities, with one being twice the other. That *might* be some kind of *wanted* bias. Or in other words, "no" bias when measuring bias differently. Depends on what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if there any mathes and shuffle again:

```
a = [1,1,2,2,3,4]
# first time shuffle
sliced = a.shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
# checking if there are matches and shuffle if there are
while sliced.combination(2).any? { |a, b| a.sort == b.sort } do
    sliced = a.shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
end
```

It is unlikely, be aware about possibility of infinity loop